# Is it true that $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This problem and solution are given.

**Problem**: If $A, B, C$ are non-singular matrices, find $(ABC)^{-1}$.

> **Solution**: $A, B, C$ are non-singular, so $A^{-1}, B^{-1}, C^{-1}$ all exist.
>   $$(ABC)^{-1}=[(AB)C]^{-1} = C^{-1}(AB)^{-1} = C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$$

I don't know if the solution is correct or not, but if it's correct could someone explain it to me? I am confused about it.

Comment: Do you know the result that if $S$ and $T$ are invertible matrices, then $(ST)^{-1} = T^{-1} S^{-1}$?

Comment: no .. it is not mentioned in the book we study and the teacher didn't tell us about this fact ! but OLD EXAMS have this kind of questions ? but what will happen when ST is raised to the negative power (-2) instead of (-1) .. will it be T^(-2).S^(-2)?

Answer (score 5):

Why dont you see for yourself?

$A^{-1}$ is that matrix (if exists) such that $A A^{-1} =I$ (the identity matrix). So just calculate the following
$$
   (A B C)(C^{-1} B^{-1} A^{-1}) = I
$$

Comment: Sorry ! I don't see any relation between my question and what you wrote ?

Comment: @Maher If $UV=I$ then $V$ is the inverse of $U$. Now, take $U=ABC$ and $V=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$, and compute the product, can you see why it must be $I$? Then $C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$ is the inverse of $ABC$.